# C# InlineShapes AddPicture

Tags: c#, .net, mailmerge

I am doing a Word MailMerge in C#. I am getting a 'Type Mismatch' error on the 'range' parameter. This is an extract from the coding.

```
   class ImageRange
    {

        public double Left;
        public double Top;
        public double Width;
        public double Height;
        
    }
```

..

```
                        ImageRange range = new ImageRange();

                        range.Left = 50;
                        range.Top = 50;
                        range.Width = 50;
                        range.Height = 50;
```

```
static string PngFileFullPath;

PngFileFullPath = 'C:\Pictures\A001.png'

var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(PngFileFullPath, false, false, range);
```

I am not on expert on C#. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or how to use the range parameter correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the optional range Parameter.

```
application.Selection.Text = string.Empty; 
// Replaces Text which was selected with nothing and then a Picture.
application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(PngFileFullPath, false, true);
```

And if that doesn't help, use the Range-Class Word provides  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range and not ImageRange.